# How to style list to looks like drop down list (with scrollbar)

Tags: jquery, html, css

can somebody help me with CSS. I have a list, and I want the list looks like drop down list, which is white background, have a scroll bar listing and etc.

Here my HTML code

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#textin1').click(function() {
        var pos = $('#textin1').offset();
        pos.top += $('#textin1').width();

        $('#dropdown').fadeIn(100);

        return false;
    });

    $('#dropdown li').click(function() {
        $('#textin1').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
    });
});
</script>

<input id="textin1" name="textin1" type="text" style="width:72px;">
<ul id="dropdown">
    <?php
    //display dropdown time for from
    $start = strtotime('12:00am');
    $end = strtotime('11:55pm');

    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 300){
        $timerfrom = date('H:i', $i);
        echo '<li>' . $timerfrom. '</li>' ;
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is your CSS code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your list doesn't inherit unwanted styles from your css,
If I'm not mistaken you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h3gSe/1/

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #2e2e2e;
    background:#f9f9f9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try slideDown and slideUp functions in Jquery.
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/